# Track tablerow Y-coordinate in pixels in android

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-tablelayout

I need to track the y-coordinate of a certain TableRow during scrolling in android. Does anyone know how to do that?

For background, my code is working fine. I have an xml layout that programmatically accepts my TableLayout. Here is a snippet

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/my_scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
    android:isScrollContainer="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/holder_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

So again, the question is: How do I track TableRow offset in android

Comment: Probably, you should make clear that you have tried to find a solution, e.g. by posting any code that you have already tried (besides the code that simply defines your scroll view).